# Magento : Add New Image For Product

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

Current there are Base Image  , Small Image , Thumbnail , Banner Size Image  options for Product . I want to add one more option say "Brand logo image" for every product. and need to display it when needed .

If this can be done by some configuration or any plugin ? any one has some idea please share 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add extra options in image tab.

Magento provide image attribute , so using image attribute you can add one extra field for image.

And on frontend you can retrieve this attribute as normal magento attribute.